# Cant connect to Https with NodeJs Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, openssl

In the console, it says that I have been connected to my server without any error but Chrome says `This site can’t provide a secure connection local host uses an unsupported protocol`.

My code

```
import express from 'express';
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.Port || 443;
// app.listen(PORT,()=>{
//     console.log(`Server connected in Port ${PORT}`);
// })

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private_key.key', (data, err) => {
  if (err) {
    return err;
  } else {
    return data;
  }
})


let certification = fs.readFileSync('./CA_certificate.arm', (data, err) => {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }),
  options = {
    key: privateKey,
    certificate: certification,
    passphrase: 'message',
    // secureProtocol: 'TLSv1.2'

  }
https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.statusCode(200);
  console.log("KHUSHI");
}).listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started in Port` + PORT);
});
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: you missing port. Try localhost:[`port`]

Comment: @Khushi as the above comment says add the PORT to your URL. And also, why would you choose the port 443 - a number used for HTTPS protocol, I mean probably you won't see any issue but I'd suggest you at least change it to 444 or as per usual in development: 3000

Comment: And you don't wanna be using `https` library when you've already imported `express`: just uncomment your `app.listen` and move it to the most bottom of your file and use that instead

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with the objects argument that you are using http.createServer(). The keys are incorrect as in the node js docs there are predefined fields/keys for the objects argument.

Comment: They're using it as per documentations [`https.createServer([options][, requestListener])`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#httpscreateserveroptions-requestlistener)

Comment: [link]https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener